# Genexus 9 y visual foxpro

Tags: genexus, visual, foxpro, generador

Instalé GX 9.0 (Generador Visual Foxpro) en Windows 10, pero tengo problemas con el visual studio. Se supone que debo instalar la versión 6.0 para que corra bien, pero creo que no existe para Win 10.

¿Que puedo hacer para ejecutar GX 9.0, con Visual Foxpro?.

Muchas gracias a todos.

Answer (score 0):

Con GeneXus 9 puedes usar Visual Foxpro 9, y esa funciona en Windows 10.
La referencia de que GeneXus 9 soporta VFP 9 está [aquí](https://www.genexus.com/developers/websac?es,,,20161)

Referencias de que puedes ejecutar VFP 9 en Windows 10 hay [aquí](http://mattslay.com/does-microsoft-visual-foxpro-run-on-windows-10/) y [aquí](https://www.foxpro.co.uk/foxpro-end-of-life-and-you/).

Answer (score 0):

Con GeneXus 9.0 puedes utilizar Visual FoxPro 6.0 y el Service Pack 5 de Visual Studio 6, pero en Windows 10 debes evitar la instalación de MDAC. El procedimiento de instalación es el siguiente:

### Visual FoxPro 6.0

- Copiar CD de VFP 6.0 a carpeta en disco.
- Desmarcar "Sólo lectura" en todas las carpetas y archivos.
- Buscar y editar el archivo setupwiz.ini
- Buscar línea con valor "VmPath="
- Eliminar todo lo que esté a continuación de "VmPath="
- Salvar archivo.
- Clic derecho en setup.exe y seleccionar "Ejecutar como administrador"
- Si el instalador pregunta para instalar MSDN contestar No.
- Si el instalador pregunta para registrarse contestar No.
- Reiniciar el equipo.
- Abrir carpeta de instalación; normalmente C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Vfp98
- Verificar fecha y tamaño de VFP6.EXE
- Debe ser 16/06/1998 y 4095 KB.

### Service Pack 5 de Visual Studio 6

A modo de ejemplo, el archivo VS6sp5Ot(en-us).exe contiene la instalación del Service Pack 5 de Visual Studio 6. Se debe descomprimir y realizar correcciones antes de instalar:

- Ejecutar para descomprimir y elegir la carpeta destino.
- Una vez descomprimidos los archivos, ir a la carpeta destino, buscar y editar el archivo sp598otr.stf
- Buscar la línea con el valor "CheckForMDAC"

Por ejemplo:

33      IsWin95     CustomAction    "sp598otr.dll,CheckForMDAC"

- Anotar el número al principio de la línea (33) y eliminarla, dejando el salto de línea.
- Buscar la línea con el valor "?  : 33"

[El 33 es el número anotado antes, que estaba al principio de la línea eliminada]

Por ejemplo:

32              Depend  "27 ?  : 33"

- Anotar el número al principio de la línea (32) y eliminarla, dejando el salto de línea.
- Ir a la línea identificada con 13, un valor Group y una serie de números

Por ejemplo:

13              Group   28 32 34 29 30  26 27 14 25  20 18 19 15 35 21 22 24 23

[Normalmente es la línea 13. Si no se ve como el ejemplo, buscar la primera línea que se le parezca]

- En la serie de números, eliminar el 32.

[El 32 es el último número anotado antes, que estaba al principio de la última línea eliminada]

- La línea debe quedar:

13              Group   28 34 29 30  26 27 14 25  20 18 19 15 35 21 22 24 23

- Salvar archivo.
- Clic derecho en setupsp5.exe y seleccionar "Ejecutar como administrador"
- Si el instalador pregunta cambiar las librerías MFC o WFC contestar No.
- Si el instalador pregunta para considerar esas librerías como las actuales contestar Sí.
- Si el instalador dice que no se instaló el Service Pack 5 ignorarlo.
- Reiniciar el equipo.
- Abrir carpeta de instalación; normalmente C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Vfp98
- Verificar fecha y tamaño de VFP6.EXE
- Debe ser 18/08/2000 y 4091 KB.

Siguiendo éste procedimiento de instalación GeneXus 9.0 funciona correctamente con VFP 6.0 en Windows 10.